# What does the -dMaxStripSize=8192 command do in ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

I was looking through the manual and cannot find anything that tells you what this command does?? -dMaxStripSize=8192  I am working on updating our Ghostscript to try and make our pdf2tiff files better quality for OCR scanning. These are the existing switches being used. 
we do not want to beef up the resolution to jeopardize file size and storage space. Any ideas are appreciated. Also answer to what the -dMaxStripSize=8192 command is doing.. Thanks in advance!!

dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dMaxStripSize=8192
-q
-r300x300
-sDEVICE=tiffg4

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation  in gs/doc/Devices.htm Section 3.4 and then  'Options'.

---

Current version of **[this documentation in Git](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Devices.htm#TIFF)**. Note, this documentation may change in step with future developments of Ghostscript.

> All TIFF drivers support creation of files that are comprised of more than a single strip. Multi-strip files reduce the memory requirement on the reader, since readers need only store and process one strip at a time. The MaxStripSize parameter controls the strip size:
>
> > -dMaxStripSize=N (non-negative integer; default = 8192)
> >
> > > Set the maximum (uncompressed) size of a strip.
> > >       The TIFF 6.0 specification, Section 7, page 27, recommends that the size of each strip be about 8 Kbytes.
>
> If the value of the MaxStripSize parameter is smaller than a single image row, then no error will be generated, and the TIFF file will be generated correctly using one row per strip. Note that smaller strip sizes increase the size of the file by increasing the size of the StripOffsets and StripByteCounts tables, and by reducing the effectiveness of the compression which must start over for each strip.
>
> If the value of MaxStripSize is 0, then the entire image will be a single strip.